# WP ALL IMPORT XML different amount of attributes per-product

Tags: xml, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, wpallimport

I am trying to import different amount of attributes for each product, instead of adding manually each attribute I want to make it automatically, I tried to use FOREACH but it is not working as I want

```
[FOREACH(Attributes/Attribute)]{.}[ENDFOREACH]
```

The xml looks like this

```
<Attributes>
  <Attribute name="Ürün Detayı"><![CDATA[ Kürk/Peluş/Şerpa ]]></Attribute>
  <Attribute name="Desen"><![CDATA[ Düz ]]></Attribute>
  <Attribute name="Materyal"><![CDATA[ Pamuklu ]]></Attribute>
  <Attribute name="Stil"><![CDATA[ Trend ]]></Attribute>
  <Attribute name="Yaka"><![CDATA[ Kalp Yaka ]]></Attribute>
  <Attribute name="Renk"><![CDATA[ Beyaz ]]></Attribute>
  <Attribute name="Kumaş / İplik"><![CDATA[ Pamuk Polyester ]]></Attribute>
  <Attribute name="Kumaş Tipi"><![CDATA[ Örme ]]></Attribute>
  <Attribute name="Kol Boyu"><![CDATA[ Askılı ]]></Attribute>
</Attributes>
```

Here is 9 attributes that one product have, different product might have more or less number of attributes or even may not have one, so I want to import them in wp all import plugin automatically without adding each of them manually, if I will do it manually and need to check each product in xml to find which product have most number of attributes which is a headache